# How to use "<Redirect>" inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my function so that when a user logs in, it checks the user's password and username and if they are both correct it should redirect to the /note url with the user ID passed through it. I have seen people use it on render(), but I would like to keep my App.jsx app simple, I think that's good practice.

I have tried using the useHistory method, but when the user inputs a data, the user needs to refresh the page manually for the new data to show. If I add a useHistory to refresh the page, it says that the location.state value is undefined.

How should I go about this problem?

Thank you

```
// Checking to see if current user's log info exists in db
function logIn(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const currentUser = users.find(
    (users) => users.username === userInput.username
  );
  if (!currentUser) {
    console.log("The Username was not found. Please try again");
  } else {
    if (currentUser.password === userInput.password) {
      // history.push("./note", { userId: currentUser._id });

      return <Redirect to={"/note/" + currentUser._id} />;
    } else {
      console.log("The password is incorrect");
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my routing code

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import NoteDashboard from "./NoteDashboard";
import Home from "./Home";
import CreateAccount from "./CreateAccount";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateAccount}></Route>
          <Route path="/note" component={NoteDashboard}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you please share the router structure of this. Maybe the history.push() problem it's related to bad routing

Comment: Should probably be `history.replace(...` to be the functional equivalent of a redirect, otherwise, the `Redirect` is only valid in a class-based component's `render` function or a functional component's return. `logIn` looks like a utility/callback function, so returning `Redirect` won't work here. Please update your question with your complete code so we can better suggest solution. Can you also specify what routing/navigation package is being used?

Comment: Sorry, i just updated to add the routing code.

Comment: Where is `logIn` defined? What component is it in? Have you tried simply doing a `history.replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it to work, but I don't know if this is good practice or not.

Inside the if statement where I check to see that it is the correct user, I call a function which changes a React Hook from false to true, then in my return statement, I say

```
{redirect ? <Redirect to={"/note/" + currentUserId} /> : null}
```

It seems to work fine, everything works. Does this look like a good solution or are there some flaws that I am not seeing.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: No problem. In my opinion, if you want to redirect from a function, the cleanest way is use history.replace(...) as @Drew Reese said. Anyway this is a valid and clean solution. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing (I found) you can do to redirect to a page from function is use `ReactDOM.hydrate`. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-testing-60wtv?file=/src/BookDetail.js) an example. Example works, **but only first time**. After that, redirection stops to works. Maybe because codesandbox concats to url the symbol `#` for some technical reason that I don't know. Try to apply this solution locally an let me know if works more tha one time.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
state = {
            username: '',
            app_pass: '',
            redirectLink: '',
            redirect: false
        };
    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
            this.setState({ redirectLink: '/user/dashboard', redirect: true });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { redirect } = this.state;
        const { redirectLink } = this.state;

        if (redirect) {
            return <Redirect to={redirectLink} />;
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes but he said "but I would like to keep my App.jsx app simple, I think that's good practice."

Comment: @Giovanni Esposito is it good practice? I feel like if i'm the one reading the code I would like the App.jsx to be simple, but I'm new to react and i'm not sure how people format their code.

Comment: In my opinion, if you want to redirect from a function, the cleanest way is use history.replace(...) as @Drew Reese said. 1 line code, no hooks involved. It's what react-navigation suggest.